# How to get table_ID(PK) of last inserted row using asp and sql

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to get value of last inserted row using following piece of code. I know @@IDENTITY and IDENTITY_SCOPE but how to use them when i am writing code in asp parametric query.

```
 SqlConnection MySQL = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BloodDonorRegistrationConnectionString"].ToString());
            string BloodReq = "insert into Blood_Request(R_Name,R_Phone,R_Blood_Group,R_City,R_Address,Date,Time) values (@Name,@cell,@BGroup,@City,@Address,@date,@time)";

            SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(BloodReq, MySQL);
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBoxName.Text);
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cell", TextBoxPhone.Text);
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BGroup", dropbownBlood.SelectedItem.Text);
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", DropDownListCity.SelectedItem.Text);
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", TextBoxLocation.Text);
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now.Date);
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
            MySQL.Open();
            Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MySQL.Close();
```

Please Help and thanks in advance.

Comment: You are doing an inser query so all you will get is an ok answer i believe. What i suggest is to add a StoreProcedure in a transaction witch seperates this in two steps. First step do the insert, second step get latest id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `scope_identity`, a full working example based upon your code would be:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BloodDonorRegistrationConnectionString"].ToString())) {
    int insertedID;
    var cmd = "insert into Blood_Request(R_Name,R_Phone,R_Blood_Group,R_City,R_Address,Date,Time) values (@Name,@cell,@BGroup,@City,@Address,@date,@time);SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";
    using (var insertCommand = new SqlCommand(cmd, con)) {
               insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBoxName.Text);
               insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cell", TextBoxPhone.Text);
               insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BGroup", dropbownBlood.SelectedItem.Text);
               insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", DropDownListCity.SelectedItem.Text);
               insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", TextBoxLocation.Text);
               insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now.Date);
               insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
               con.Open();
               insertedID = (int)insertCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    }
```

}

Comment: so there is no need to use ExecuteNonQuery()? as I am inserting data which would be type of varchar.

Comment: @IbtisamTanveer You need a result back within a query so I would not use `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: yeah I understand that why I should use cmd.ExecuteScalar but I have to insert data on same time

Answer (score 2):

Use `cmd.ExecuteScalar` instead of `Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`. You can also use `ExecuteReader` if you want to return more values.

And in your Sql use `OUTPUT INSERTED.ID` as in

```
string BloodReq = "insert into Blood_Request(R_Name,R_Phone,R_Blood_Group,R_City,R_Address,Date,Time)
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
values (@Name,@cell,@BGroup,@City,@Address,@date,@time)"
```

Comment: so there is no need to use ExecuteNonQuery()? as I am inserting data which is of type of varchar.

Comment: If you use `ExecuteNonQuery()` you can't retrieve returning data. `Output` is very powerful technology. On `update`, for example, you can actually return both, inserted and deleted: `OUTPUT Inserted.Name, Deleted.Name`. when you use `scope_identity()` it is limited and you essentially run 2 commands. Output is all in one and very flexible.

Answer (score 1):

```
...    
string BloodReq = "insert into Blood_Request(R_Name,R_Phone,R_Blood_Group,R_City,R_Address,Date,Time) values (@Name,@cell,@BGroup,@City,@Address,@date,@time); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS IID";

...
var insertedID = (Int32)Cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```